# overloaded method value async with alternatives:

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo

When I have the following code everything compiles fine.

```
 def create(name: String, age: Int) = Action.async {
    val json = Json.obj(
      "name" -> name,
      "age" -> age,
      "created" -> new java.util.Date().getTime())

    collection.insert(json).map(lastError =>
      Ok("Mongo LastError: %s".format(lastError)))
  }
```

But when extract the content to another method as follows

```
 def create(name: String, age: Int) = Action.async {
   createPerson(name,age)
 }

  def createPerson(name: String, age: Int) = Action.async {
    val json = Json.obj(
      "name" -> name,
      "age" -> age,
      "created" -> new java.util.Date().getTime())

    collection.insert(json).map(lastError =>
      Ok("Mongo LastError: %s".format(lastError)))
  }
```

it gives the error

```
[error] /media/pubudu/NTFSPartition/projects/catnet/data-collector-backend/app/controllers/Application.scala:50: overloaded method value async with alternatives:
[error]   [A](bodyParser: play.api.mvc.BodyParser[A])(block: play.api.mvc.Request[A] => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result])play.api.mvc.Action[A] <and>
[error]   (block: play.api.mvc.Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result])play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] <and>
[error]   (block: => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result])play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]
[error]  cannot be applied to (play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent])
[error]   def create(name: String, age: Int) = Action.async {
```

Isn't the two code sections doing the same thing? If not, how can I extract the content of the method without getting the error? What I want to do is to call the extracted method from two different places.

Comment: No, The create method expects the return to be Result , but you are calling another action in this function which has the returns Action[AnyContent]

Comment: @curious Thanks, If you can make that an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I have explained it in ans a bit more. check that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `create` method expects the return type to be `Future[Result]`, but the calling of `createPerson` returns `Action[AnyContent]`. You can correct it by making following changes:

```
def create(name: String, age: Int) = Action.async {
   createPerson(name,age).map(lastError =>
      Ok("Mongo LastError: %s".format(lastError)))
 }

  def createPerson(name: String, age: Int):Future[String] = {
    val json = Json.obj(
      "name" -> name,
      "age" -> age,
      "created" -> new java.util.Date().getTime())

    collection.insert(json)
  }
```